# Multi level login table design

Tags: mysql

I need to create a multi level application where user detail are stored in a mysql table called Users.

Now I need to allow user to create sub-user or client account. So there will be admin, user and client account that can login in the site.

My question is: how can I group the admin and the his own created sub-user and client?

I should create a second table with the not-admin details? or is better to have the client and user in the same table of admin and then create a self relationship on the table?

Comment: There's no absolutely right or wrong solution. It all depends on what you're doing and how fine-grained permissions should ultimately be. Look into Access Control Lists (ACL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep all accounts in the same table and add a `parentAccount` column to store the primary key of the account's parent.

Comment: Just a little clarification: if I create an admin, I should set the prent to null or should I set the parent equal to admin self?

Comment: @Tropicalista however you want to do it; I'd set it to null to represent an account with no parent.

Answer (score 4):

Here's more or less how I've done it in the past:

```
actions
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    description         varchar(50) // Delete users, Edit something, etc.

roles
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    site_account_id     unsigned int(F site_accounts.id)
    description         varchar(50) // Client Admin, Client User, etc.

roles_actions
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    role_id             unsigned int(F roles.id)
    action_id           unsigned int(F actions.id)

site_accounts
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    name                varchar(50) // Client 1, Client 2, etc.

users
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    site_account_id     unsigned int(F site_accounts.id)
    username            varchar(32)
    password            varbinary(255)
    email               varchar(255)

users_roles
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    user_id             unsigned int(F users.id)
    role_id             unsigned int(F roles.id)
```

You'll create a `role` for "Client Administrators" and this role will have all the permissions that a client can possibly have. Then you'll create a `site account` whenever you sign up a new client and you'll assign them the role of "Client Administrator".

You'll need to write the code that lets them create their own `roles` (which will be associated with their site_account_id) and also let them assign any of their `actions` to each of those new `roles`. This gives them complete control over what roles they want and what permissions each role has.

You'll also need to write the code that lets them add/update/delete users (again, each of those users will be associated with their site_account_id).

This makes it easy for you to see what roles/users belong to each of your clients and whenever you lose one you can delete all of their data by simply deleting their `site_accounts` record.

This is just a rough example. There's a lot more that can go into something like this so you'll have to figure out how fine-grained you want it to be.

Comment: This answer really helped me sort out user privileges on my website.